# Netlify env variables: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, netlify, remix, netlify-cli

My Remix app was working correctly when my various api values were inline. I then moved them to a .env file and imported the file to Netlify. My file now uses `process.env.[ENV_VARIABLE]` to access the environment variables. When I run `netlify dev`, I get the following console error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

Comment: If you're using `process` in client-side code, this is expected. `process` only works in Node.js.